# update nested json key

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a data I am reading into `data={'data1':}`
I am writing a lot of data to that key.

```
subData = {'1':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5}
data['data1' = subData
```

When I have to open the `data` object again.  how do I append more subdata to the key `data1`.

```
moreSubData = {'6':1,'7':2,'8':3,'9':4,'10':5}
```

I want to push `moreSubData` into the `data['data1']`

so the total data would be

```
`data['data1']` = {'1':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':1,'7':2,'8':3,'9':4,'10':5}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python)

Comment: specifically `data['data1'] = {**data['data1'], **moreSubData}` should work for you